# Nautilus bookmarks to Google Drive not maintained on restart

Tags: nautilus, google-drive, bookmarks

New user here with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

I happily discovered that Nautilus allows me to browse my Google Drive contents, and was even happier when I found out how to bookmark my most-often used sub-folders, but my joy was ruined when the bookmarks aren't maintained after a logout or reboot. The bookmarks still show in the file browser window, but they all now just point to top of my Google Drive, so I have to delete & re-bookmark them, not optimal at all.

Is there anyway to preserve the bookmarks? Or any another way to achieve a similar result? I'm not a complete Linux noob & am open to (almost) anything.

Thanks in advance.